# Totally confused attempting to integrate a map...Best way forwards?

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap

I have been looking to implement a map in my website, and have really hit a brick wall - Have read so much, but am very confused. I just wonder if someone could offer a little help?

I have developed an Android App which generates a list of lat/long pairs and stores them in a remote MySQL DB. All I want to do is mark these points on a map, with a little pop up when clicked, indicating some other information about the user.

I have so far looked at Google Maps API and OpenStreetMap, although I really don't know where to begin! I don't know whether I should use Google Maps, as I'm concerned about the API query limit? Should I be?

Would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction!

Thank you

Comment: you want to implement map in your app or want to host that on your website

Comment: THanks for your reply Hitesh. I would like to host a map on the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing some markers and popups isn't really complicated with OpenStreetMap and [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/):

- [simple OpenLayers marker example](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Marker_Example)
- [dynamic markers from a database](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Dynamic_POI) ([example result](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html))

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I have been looking for. Without being rude to the other respondents, you also appear to have actually read my question! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use google maps javascript v3 and make the required changes
Please refer 
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Thank you. Should I be concerned about the query limit though? Or is that sufficiently high I needn't worry?

Comment: Having looked at it, I won't be able to use the API linked. The mapping facility is behind a login page, and is only accessible as a result of the paid android app.
Can you suggest anything else? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: i dont think there is any query limit. Also http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#map_simple_v3, check this one.  It tells you how to use the one.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API limit is something like 25k (or was it 250k?) per day - so unless the app you're making proves to be *really* popular, you won't have to worry about it

Comment: Thanks. However I am still concerned about access. Simply put, a login code is sent by the app, to another contact, who can then log in to my website on their computer and view the map - its essentially a paid service, and I'm just concerned this isn't allowable...The google web-page states it must be freely accessible unfortunately.